# What happen if I switch those labels when generating Artwork

Tags: pcb-design, orcad

What will happen if I edit the label "TOP" and write is as "BOTTOM" and vice versa with the other one? Will the manufactured board be ok, or will everything be mirrored? (When BOTTOM layer is mirrored in the design, as it should be)

[image]

We designed this board and we put routes in TOP layer (not mirrored), but we were supposed to have routes in BOTTOM layer. Parts in BOTTOM layer, which were supposed to be in TOP layer, are mirrored. So I wonder if renaming this in createing artwork would fix this thing, or mess up everything.

Comment: You might want to try creating a temporary layer and moving everything on (say) TOP to that layer, then copying everything from BOTTOM to top etc., then delete the empty temp layer. But whatever you do make sure that you check with a Gerber viewer as @M D suggests to make sure that nothing is mirrored.

Comment: Note that the Gerber files sent to the board shop should not be mirrored - they should all be as if viewed from the top/component side of the board.  It is up to the board shop to manipulate the files as needed to produce the board. (but any text on the "Bottom" copper, mask, or silkscreen files should be mirrored so it will read right on the finished board).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fabricator doesn't necessarily care what you call the layers.  They are going to build the PCB in the layer order you tell them and based on the gerber files named what you call out.  Now, obviously naming something "TOP" that you want on the bottom is going to create confusion.  You have the option to mirror the particular film when generating the artwork.  My recommendation would be to generate the artwork until you get what you want in the gerber view (use and independent gerber viewer to verify/validate), and then rename the output files to match what you want prior to packaging for sending to the fabricator.  This is obviously a little bit of a hack, and now your design files won't match the gerbers exactly, but unless you have the ability to swap the layers around in the tool (I am an Altium user and don't have enough experience to comment on OrCAD), I can't think of a better way to do this.  Just remember, the fabricator will build it how you tell them to build it based on the artwork you provide.